# Having issues inside my WHERE clause conditions. <> and AND OR

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a workout generation type of application and I'm having a problem with a mysql query. The problem I'm having is I keep grabbing more than 1 of certain ExerciseIDs when I specifically have them as a Not equal <> in the where clause.

```
SELECT `Exercise_Name` , `Body_Part_Focus` , `Video_FileName` , `Alignment_Body_Position` ,  `Description_Movement_Technique` , `Tip1_Trainer_Tips` , `Sets` , `Post_Season` , `Off_Season`, `Pre_Season` , `In_Season` , `Measurement_Type` , `Measurement_Type_Label` ,`ExerciseID` 
FROM `tbl_exercises` WHERE 
`exrcs_age_approp` = '14 to 17' 
AND `exrcs_prgssn_lvl` = 'I' OR `exrcs_prgssn_lvl` = 'II' 
AND `Athletic_Skill` = 'ROM' OR `Exercise_Subskill` = 'ROM' 
AND `Body_Part_Focus` = 'Torso' 
AND `ExerciseID` <> 89 
AND `ExerciseID` <> 58 
AND `ExerciseID` <> 178 
AND `ExerciseID` <> 249 
ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Also am I doing the AND OR clause correct? 
I'm trying to say THIS AND THIS or THIS AND THIS.. ect.. but I think my mysql might be interpreting that wrong too... I normally don't touch back-end stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding parentheses around the OR clauses. Their priority isn't what you might think.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to a lack of parenthesis between your `AND` and `OR` conditions. I rewrote your query with a few simplifications using `IN` and `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT `Exercise_Name` , `Body_Part_Focus` , `Video_FileName` , `Alignment_Body_Position` ,  `Description_Movement_Technique` , `Tip1_Trainer_Tips` , `Sets` , `Post_Season` , `Off_Season`, `Pre_Season` , `In_Season` , `Measurement_Type` , `Measurement_Type_Label` ,`ExerciseID` 
FROM `tbl_exercises`
WHERE `exrcs_age_approp` = '14 to 17' 
AND `exrcs_prgssn_lvl` IN ('I', 'II')
AND (`Athletic_Skill` = 'ROM' OR `Exercise_Subskill` = 'ROM')
AND `Body_Part_Focus` = 'Torso' 
AND `ExerciseID` NOT IN (89, 58, 178, 249) 
ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need parentheses for the logic in your `WHERE` clause.  I would suggest:

```
WHERE `exrcs_age_approp` = '14 to 17' AND
      `exrcs_prgssn_lvl` IN ('I', 'II') AND
      (`Athletic_Skill` = 'ROM' OR `Exercise_Subskill` = 'ROM') AND
      `Body_Part_Focus` = 'Torso' AND
      `ExerciseID` NOT IN (89, 58, 178, 249)
```

`IN` and `NOT IN` should also help with the logic.